# GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given

Tags: php, laravel-4, guzzle

Ok i used "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0" for laravel.

it works on the server, but it does not work on my XAMPP, i don't know what is the problem. This is the error code.

Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given

This is the code:

```
$param_data = array(
    'api_user'  => Config::get('sendgrid.api_user'),
    'api_key'   => Config::get('sendgrid.api_key'),
    'list'      => Config::get('sendgrid.list'),
    'email'     => 'xxxxxxx@yahoo.com',
);

$client = new Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);
$res    = $client->request(
    'GET',
    'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/get.json',
    [
    'query' => $param_data
    ]
);

$arr_res = json_decode($res->getBody());
print_r( $arr_res );
```

Comment: You should follow following answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324500/setting-curl-parameters-for-fabpot-goutte-client/38608057#38608057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same error I resolved it like this in my code

```
 $param_data = array(
        'api_user'  => Config::get('sendgrid.api_user'),
        'api_key'   => Config::get('sendgrid.api_key'),
        'list'      => Config::get('sendgrid.list'),
        'email'     => 'xxxxxxx@yahoo.com',
    );

    $client = new Client();
    $client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);
    $res    = $client->request(
               array(
                      'GET', 
                      'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/get.json?query='.$param_data,
                   ));

    $arr_res = json_decode($res->getBody());
    print_r( $arr_res );
```

Also if your using Laravel request and Guzzle Request in same page so you need to use it like.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;
```

Try this hope this will work for you :)

Comment: does not work. Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

Reading the guzzle documentation I change the structure of my request:

```
$client = new Client([
// Base URI is used with relative requests
'base_uri' => 'https://mytesturl.com/',]);
$res = $client->request('GET', 'processJobs', ['verify' => false]);
$arr_res= json_decode($res->getBody());
echo $arr_res;
```

The problem lies in how the request method receives the parameters, there are many ways to build your request but if this messages appears to you. I recommend use this way